# How to use switch() with multiple arguments?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I want to use switch instead of if-else as I've that it's better when there are many if-else. The problem is that I've multiple arguments, so I don't know how to handle that.

Here are my if-else's:

```
if(frame.height()/2 + margin < pt.y){
            System.out.println("down");
            drone.getCommandManager().down(20).doFor(100);
            drone.getCommandManager().hover();
        }
        else if(frame.height()/2 - margin > pt.y){
            System.out.println("up");
            drone.getCommandManager().up(20).doFor(100);
            drone.getCommandManager().hover();
        }
        else if(frame.width()/2+margin < pt.x){
            drone.getCommandManager().spinRight(30).doFor(33);
            drone.getCommandManager().hover();
            System.out.println("RIGHT");

        }
        else if(frame.width()/2-margin > pt.x){
            drone.getCommandManager().spinLeft(30).doFor(33);
            drone.getCommandManager().hover();
            System.out.println("LEFT");
        }

        else if(frame.width()/2+margin > pt.x && frame.width()/2-margin<pt.x){
            System.out.println("GO");
            drone.getCommandManager().forward(30).doFor(time+2000);
            drone.getCommandManager().hover();
        }

        else{
            drone.getCommandManager().hover();
        }
```

Comment: You can only use switch statement if you have single variable to control the flow. In above example you have many conditions to check, here in this particular case SWITCH statement is not recomended.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

The labels in a `switch` must be compile time evaluable constant expressions, and must compare *exactly* with the thing being switched on.

Answer (score 3):

You might step back for a second and read about the [TDA](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) principle.

What you are doing here in essence is: query the state of something, and then make decisions on how something else should be reacting to that. Thing is - that is really not object-oriented thinking.

You could instead go for:

```
interface CommandManagerUpdater {
  void updateOnNewDirection(CommandManager);
}

enum Direction { UP, DOWN, ... };

class DirectionDetector {
   Direction getNewDirection(Frame, x, yz, whatever you need)

class CommandManagerUpdaterFactory {
  CommandManagerUpdater generateUpdaterFor(Direction newDirection) {
```

If you have the above means in place, you can write up the whole thing as:

```
Direction newDirection = someDetector.getNewDirection(...)
CommandManagerUpdater updater = theFactory.generateUpdaterFor(newDirection);
updater.updateOnNewDirection(commandManager);
```

Long story short: in OO programming, you should avoid this kind of if/else/switch statements. Instead: you create proper OO abstractions; and use factories and polymorphism. And let me be very clear about this: **switch** statements are **not** the answer to your problems. They are just a syntactically-marginally-improved version of if/else trees.

Of course, in the end, you need to a switch on "direction". But: you hide that switch inside the factory. There should be as few places as possible concerned about knowing **all** the potential directions.

Finally: keep an eye on code duplication. Check out how many times you have that "hoover()" call in your code - most them could go away! You know, when you go "hoover" all the time, for each of your direction; then you call write down that call **once unconditionally**, instead of repeating it n times in each of your branches!

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with what Jägermeister said. I think **you should use proper OO principles** to improve your code, but if you really wanted a switch...

You should convert the expressions you have into single values. You could use an enum like:

```
public enum Result {
    A, B, C, D, E, F
}
```

Of course you should **give it meaningful names!**

Then you can have a method which converts the expression into result:

```
public Result calculateResult() {
    if (frame.height() / 2 + margin < pt.y) {
        return A;
    } else if (frame.height() / 2 - margin > pt.y) {
        return B;
    } else if (frame.width() / 2 + margin < pt.x) {
        return C;
    } else if (frame.width() / 2 - margin > pt.x) {
        return D;
    } else if (frame.width() / 2 + margin > pt.x && frame.width() / 2 - margin < pt.x) {
        return E;
    } else {
        return F;
    }
}
```

Which in the end you can use in the switch:

```
switch (calculateResult()) {
    case A:
        System.out.println("down");
        drone.getCommandManager().down(20).doFor(100);
        drone.getCommandManager().hover();
        break;
    case B:
        System.out.println("up");
        drone.getCommandManager().up(20).doFor(100);
        drone.getCommandManager().hover();
        break;
    case C:
        drone.getCommandManager().spinRight(30).doFor(33);
        drone.getCommandManager().hover();
        System.out.println("RIGHT");
        break;
    case D:
        drone.getCommandManager().spinLeft(30).doFor(33);
        drone.getCommandManager().hover();
        System.out.println("LEFT");
        break;
    case E:
        System.out.println("GO");
        drone.getCommandManager().forward(30).doFor(time + 2000);
        drone.getCommandManager().hover();
        break;
    case F:
        drone.getCommandManager().hover();
        break;
}
```

Comment: Be careful here: you are exactly taking the route ... one should avoid; I call that the **enum** trap. You see ... what happens when you add another instance to your enum? You have to go back and rework each any of your switch statements.

Comment: Exactly, I fully agree with you.